# User authentication with Servlets on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I'm new to web dev, and trying to build an application using google app engine's java standard environment, which will require user authentication. I'd like to provide authentication which requires only a username and password of the user, as opposed to a phone number or social account.

As I look through the options listed in app engine's auth tutorial, if I'm understanding them correctly, none of them allow login without a phone number or social account? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/oauth/

If so, are there alternatives available while still using app engine? I've read some about 'web container managed authentication' but I'm not sure if its something app engine will support, or if its a full solution.

Is it possible/feasible to roll fully custom authentication in the app engine standard environment? As I search for custom authentication tutorials I see a lot of articles recommending against this, but it's not clear to me what the alternative is.

Thanks for any information

Answer (score 1):

As it's mention on the [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) documents of Google Cloud, it's important for you and your users security to authenticate using well proven and debugged code. Google offers [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) which let's users log in with an Email and password.

If you still want to implement the authorize part on your own, you can use your preferred web framework and probably it will have an authorizing process.

For example, in python you can use [Django authorize system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/) to provide users for a custom way to log in.

But, as I said before, I highly recommend you to use the Google APIs for authorizing as they are OpenID certificated.